# Issue with sending data from databridge in EMQX to Influxdb

Tags: http, webhooks, influxdb, emqx

I`m having an issue with sending data to my bucket in influxdb through a databridge in emqx which is subscribed to an mqtt broker. it keeps saying unexcepted API access in the emqx log.

This is the error i received:

```
2023-11-22T18:38:35.783000-05:00 [error] msg: unrecoverable_error, mfa: emqx_resource_buffer_worker:handle_query_result_pure/3(890), id: <<"bridge:webhook:EMQX_WH_D">>, reason: {unrecoverable_error,#{body => <<"{\"code\":\"unauthorized\",\"message\":\"unauthorized access\"}">>,headers => [{<<"content-type">>,<<"application/json; charset=utf-8">>},{<<"x-influxdb-build">>,<<"OSS">>},{<<"x-influxdb-version">>,<<"v2.7.1">>},{<<"x-platform-error-code">>,<<"unauthorized">>},{<<"date">>,<<"Wed, 22 Nov 2023 23:38:35 GMT">>},{<<"content-length">>,<<"55">>}],status_code => 401}}
```

And this is the HTTP i used:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8086/api/v2/write?org={organization i used}&bucket={bucket i used}&precision=ns
```

I was trying to connect the databridge to influxdb through an http server and it never worked

Comment: The error seems pretty clear - you are not authorized to query InfluxDB. Try to first make a successful request manually. You can use cURL and the example in the official [docs](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2/write-data/developer-tools/api/#send-a-write-request).

Comment: Thanks, I just got it to work the issue was that the user wasn`t authorized to write inside Influxdb. I just had to make an admin user.